# Is a return to previous personality possible in Schizophrenia?

Tags: personality, psychiatry, schizophrenia

I'm reading *Memory Disorders in Psychiatric Practice* by  *German E. Berrios* and  *John R. Hodges* (2000). The section on The Ganser Syndrome has [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxVFg.png) table (from page 449) contrasting Schizophrenia and the The Ganser Syndrome. The third row of the table reads:

> \begin{array}{c|c|c|}  &   \text{Ganser Syndrome} & \text{Schizophrenia } 
> \\\hline \text{Return to previous personality possible} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} 
>  \\\hline \end{array}

The book doesn't elaborate as to how a return to previous personality is not possible in Schizophrenia. My own (weak) understanding was that some people do make a full and complete recovery indefinitely - taking that to mean a return to previous personality happens. I would appreciate if someone could elaborate or share a source that provides an explanation for this claim.

> Is a return to previous personality possible in Schizophrenia?

Comment: It depends somewhat on the definition of personality.The practical answer would be no, but I guess you are talking about a single psychotic episode that has resolved. Which I would not classify as schizophrenia.

Comment: @r0berts Thanks for the comment. Isn't a single episode that lasts sufficiently long enough considered schizophrenia even if it has resolved indefinitely? Most non-Schizophrenia type psychosis' (e.g. brief/transient) have a very short cut off period (lasts > 1 day but < a month etc).